# How do i show enum values in a combo-box?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, combobox

How do i show enum values in a combo-box? The code below result in the combobox having all displayed names being "caseHandler.cState". I wanted it to have the actual names of the enum values.

My enum is defined as follows:

```
public enum caseState
{
    Active = 1,
    Finished,
    Problem
}
```

I have a class that is defined as this:

```
public class cState
{    
    public string _name;
    public int _id;

    public cState(int id,string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _id = id;
    }
}
```

And the code for populating my combobox:

```
ArrayList AL = new ArrayList();

foreach (string cs in Enum.GetNames(typeof(caseState)))
{
    cState aEnum = new cState((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(caseState),cs),cs);
    AL.Add(aEnum);
}


cbState.DisplayMember = "_name";
cbState.ValueMember = "_id";

cbState.DataSource = AL;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding an enum to a WinForms combo box, and then setting it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906899/binding-an-enum-to-a-winforms-combo-box-and-then-setting-it)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried to use

```
cbState.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(caseState));
```

And when retrieving data just Parse it

Comment: @ Stecya - this worked. But can you explain to me why the code i've written doesn't work?

Comment: @ Stecya - ok, i found the mistake. I should've implemented _name and _id as properties, then it would have worked.

Answer (score 4):

Here My Code , you can have text and value together and fill Combobox

```
 public enum LayerType : int
{

    [Description("محوطه")]
    Area = 1,


    [Description("ساختمان")]
    Building = 2,


    [Description("بارانداز")]
    Wharf = 3,}

drpLayer.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LayerType))
             .Cast<Enum>()
             .Select(value => new
        {
        (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()), typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute).Description,
        value
         })
        .OrderBy(item => item.value)
        .ToList();
            drpLayer.DisplayMember = "Description";
            drpLayer.ValueMember = "value";
```