# adding enum values to a simple combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

i have a really simple question to ask about C# and WPF.
My Question will follow after this attempt of mine:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in Races)
            {
                cbRace.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    enum Races
    {
        Human=1,
        Dwarf,
        Elf,
        Orc,
        Goblin,
        Vampire,
        Centaur
    }
```

Ok so, my question is how will I add the values(e.g. Human,dwarf,elf....) into the combo box: cbRace? sorry I'm new to C# so i would rally appreciate it if someone can help me out :), thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't the above code working for you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Races)))
        {
            cbRace.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    enum Races
    {
        Human = 1,
        Dwarf,
        Elf,
        Orc,
        Goblin,
        Vampire,
        Centaur
    }
```

Comment: Enum.GetValues will return your type enum list.

Answer (score 24):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
cbRace.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Races));
```

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906899/binding-an-enum-to-a-winforms-combo-box-and-then-setting-it) answer for more information on setting and retrieving the enum values.

Comment: Note: In WPF it is `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: This is best answer!!

Answer (score 5):

This would perhaps be the easiest way to set the ComboBox items:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cbRace.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Races));
    cbRace.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

It is not necessary to loop over the enum values, just set the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a preferred solution as Clemens has already given you that but if you wanted to add in the XAML directly you could also do

```
<ComboBox>
    <urCode:Races>Human</urCode:Races>
    <urCode:Races>Dwarf</urCode:Races>
    <urCode:Races>Elf</urCode:Races>
</ComboBox>
```

you could also implment an IValueConverter that when bound to a Type, returns the Enum.GetValues

Answer (score 2):

Shortest Way to add Enum Values to Combobox in C#

```
class User{

public enum TYPE { EMPLOYEE, DOCTOR, ADMIN };

}
```

// Add this class to your form load event of Form Cunstructor

```
cmbUserType.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(User.TYPE)));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
cbRace.Datasource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Races));
```

to databind your enum to the combobox and then use selectedValue and selectedText properties of your combobox to retreive names and values;

Answer (score 0):

```
cmbUserType.Items.AddRange(core.Global.ToObjectArray(Enum.GetValues(typeof(STATUS))));
public enum STATUS { INACTIVE, ACTIVE }
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Given something like

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public ComboBoxItem(int id, string text)
    {
      Id = id;
      Text = text;
    }
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString() => Text;
}
```

you could use

```
public static IEnumerable<ComboBoxItem> GetAsComboBoxItems<TEnum>()
{
  foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
  {
    yield return new ComboBoxItem((int)enumValue, enumValue.ToString());
  }
}
```

and then

```
cbRace.DataSource = GetAsComboBoxItems<Races>().ToList();
```