# filling combobox from API

Tags: c#, .net

I have two projects in my solution:

1. The API: https://github.com/foxip/mollie-api-csharp
2. The project where Iretrieve and send data from and to my API

I want to fill a ComboBox with `methods` but when i try to do it how they say I should, it doesn't work. This is what I tried:

```
using Mollie.Api;

// ...

MollieClient mollieClient = new MollieClient();
mollieClient.setApiKey("test_1234");

Method methods = new Method();
methods = Mollie.Api.Method.all();
```

Under all there is a red line saying:

> Error 1   'Mollie.Api.Method' does not contain a definition for 'all'

When I write `Mollie.Api.Method.*`, the helper gives me then all the possible methods at *, but how can I get them automatically into my ComboBox?

EDIT: this works for me:
`cboMethod.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Method));`

Comment: It is not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to get list of some class methods (say, through reflection)?

Comment: Looking at his question history, he's talking about mollie-api-csharp and [`Method` is an enum](https://github.com/foxip/mollie-api-csharp/blob/master/Mollie.cs#L43).

Comment: yes, you are right @GrawCube i want to get those payment methods in my combobox so my customer can choose one, i am sorry that i may ask really obvious things but i am not really expierienced in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding an enum to a WinForms combo box, and then setting it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906899/binding-an-enum-to-a-winforms-combo-box-and-then-setting-it) - see the answer with most votes for your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541156/996081

Comment: after alot of searching i found the answer i needed:

`cboMethod.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Method));`