# Setting the start value of an enum ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

been searching for a solution for this problem, found plenty solutions, but nothing changed my code's behaviour. This is in WinForms.

I am loading a form with a ComboBox, that contains the values and names of this enum, that is inside a class named "Node".

```
class Node
{
    public enum NodeType { Yield, Home, Parking, Light, None, Inbound, Outbound }
    public NodeType Type;
}
```

Then in my form, I have a ComboBox named "Type", which is set up like so (from the constructor):

```
Node node = new Node();
node.Type = Node.NodeType.Home;

Type = new ComboBox();
Type.Location = new Point(77, 41);
Type.Size = new Size(121, 24);
Type.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
Type.DisplayMember = "Name";
Type.ValueMember = "Value";
Type.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Node.NodeType));
Type.SelectedValue = node.Type;
Controls.Add(Type);
```

When the program runs, the list shows all the names, and on closing the form I am able to retrieve the selected value via. Type.SelectedValue. **My problem** is that the ComboBox doesn't start at the value that the Node is already set at. Essentially the line

```
Type.SelectedValue = node.Type;
```

doesn't do anything. I've tried using SelectedItem which didn't change anything, and

```
Type.SelectedIndex = (int)node.Type;
```

Which caused an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

So, my question is: how do I set the start value of the ComboBox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding an enum to a WinForms combo box, and then setting it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906899/binding-an-enum-to-a-winforms-combo-box-and-then-setting-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in that code.

First, `enum` does not have `Name` and `Value` properties (in fact it does not have any property), so `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` cannot be used and should be left blank (default). Which in turn means `SelectedValue` cannot be used and you need to use `SelectedItem` instead.

Second, you are using **list data bound** mode for the list portion of your `ComboBox` by setting `DataSource` property instead of populating `Items`, which is fine, but data binding occurs later in the process, so inside the constructor the `Items` property is empty and `SelectedItem` has no effect. In order to fix that, you need to move the data initialization part to your form `Load` event.

So, in your form constructor you'll have this:

```
Type = new ComboBox();
Type.Location = new Point(77, 41);
Type.Size = new Size(121, 24);
Type.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
Controls.Add(Type);
```

and in your form `Load` event - this:

```
Node node = new Node();
node.Type = Node.NodeType.Home;

Type.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Node.NodeType));
Type.SelectedItem = node.Type;
```

Comment: Solved the issue, thank you for explaining the errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Type.SelectedIndex = index from your enum, for example the enum is {"apple", "pear", "pineapple"}, and you want pear by deafult, so Type.SelectedIndex = 1

Comment: This is what I tried by doing Type.SelectedIndex = (int)node.Type; which causes an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, even if I just enter 2 instead of (int)node.Type, samething happens.

Comment: if you want to select Light, try Type.SelectedValue = node.Type.Light

Comment: Tried: Type.SelectedValue = Node.NodeType.Light; The ComboBox still starts at "Yield", the first value in the enumerator.