# Enum variable c#

Tags: c#, enums

This is my enum:

```
public enum SomeTest
{
  Undefined = 0,
  Gram = 1,
  Kilogram = 2
}
```

And this is my Test class:

```
private SomeTest test;

public Test (SomeTest test)
{
  this.test = test;
}
```

I want to set to `test` my `Settings.Default.Test` Is it possible?

```
asd = new Test(Test)
```

Comment: What is your `Settings.Default.Test`?

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default.Test => type is string

Comment: @TheNewBegining What do you expect the behaviour of assigning a `string` to `SomeTest` to be? They're different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Settings.Default.Test` is a `String`, you can **use [`Enum.Parse(..)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx)** for that:

```
asd = new Test(Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeTest),Settings.Default.Test))
```

When you run this in the `csharp` console:

```
csharp> public enum SomeTest
      > {
      >   Undefined = 0,
      >   Gram = 1,
      >   Kilogram = 2
      > }
csharp>  
csharp> Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeTest),"Gram")      
Gram
```

Note that it will **throw an `ArgumentException` if the string does not match an enum value**:

```
csharp> Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeTest),"Foo")  
System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Foo' was not found.
```

Comment: If I have a combobx and set to `test` my combobox's selected item, is it this simple as well?

Comment: @TheNewBegining: in that case you better use the values as an enum as datasource, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541156/67579).

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem can you please help me out in how we can handle this exception and return a default string in return.