# Not able to set "SelectedValue" in Combobox bound with enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms, combobox

I want to set default value (rather than first one) in combobox through SelectedItem/SelectedText/SelectedValue (from any one way).

I have tried to resolve it through many different ways. Like I have set enum to Key Value Pair. Tried to use "SelectedIndex". It is showing '-1' while debugging. In other "selected*" options, value is 'null'. I do not know what is happening. I have attached code. Please take a look and help me to resolve it. Thank you.

```
            ComboBox cmbxType= new ComboBox();
            cmbxType.FormattingEnabled = true;
            cmbxType.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cmbxType.Margin = new Padding(3, 6, 3, 3);
            cmbxType.Name = "cmbxType";
            cmbxType.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 28);
            cmbxType.TabIndex = 1;
            cmbxType.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(StateType));
            cmbxType.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cmbxType_SelectedIndexChanged);
            cmbxType.ValueMember = (workflowRows).ToString();
            cmbxType.SelectedValue = 2
```

PS: I am creating this combobox after creating form and the problematic case is with enum only.

Comment: With `Enum.GetValues(typeof(StateType));` you have an Array of `StateType` members. So, each Item in the ComboBox is a `StateType` object. You cannot set the `ValueMember` (there's not named selector, so neither `DisplayMember` can be set). The display value is `[StateType].ToString()`. If you want to select an item with one of the values of the Enumerator, cast the `int` value to `StateType`: `cmbxType.SelectedItem = (StateType)2`. You should, in this case, validate the value with `if Enum.IsDefined(typeof(StateType), 2) (...)`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906899/binding-an-enum-to-a-winforms-combo-box-and-then-setting-it) you can only set the selected item after the data bindings are assigned. If you select the item when the `OnLoad` event occures it should work. Below is a working example.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        internal enum StateType
        {
            State1, 
            State2, 
            State3
        }

        internal class DemoForm : Form
        {
            ComboBox cmbxType = new ComboBox();

            public DemoForm()
            {
                cmbxType.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(StateType));
                Controls.Add(cmbxType);
            }

            protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnLoad(e);
                cmbxType.SelectedItem = StateType.State3;
            }
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new DemoForm());
        }
    }
}
```